# Applet performance: loading all jars at startup or only when class is needed?

Tags: java, jar, applet, load

Currently, my applet is loaded by using few lib jars, I put them in archive:

```
<applet
archive="MainJar.jar,lib/jar1.jar,lib/jar2.jar,lib/jar3.jar" 
code="start.MainClass.class"
name = "Testing" 
width=1280 height=800>
<PARAM NAME="zoomon" VALUE="true">
</applet>
```

May I know:

- Are all of my lib jars (jar1.jar, jar2.jar, jar3.jar) downloaded when applet starts or they are only downloaded if the classes are accessed?
- If the lib classes are accessed again, lib jars can be used as already downloaded or they will be re-downloaded?
- How can I download all jars (including lib jars) at applet startup?
- How can I include all lib jars in my MainJar.jar?

Answer (score 2):

- Eagerly (using that form of launching an applet).<sup>1</sup>
- They should be cached.  One of the problems for applet developers is getting an applet to load an *updated* Jar, rather than use the cached version.
- The way the applet tag is written, it is automatic.<sup>1</sup>
- If by 'include in main Jar' you mean deploying just one 'fat' Jar containing everything, don't do that.  It is better to keep Jars separate for a number of reasons.

---

1. [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) provides the option for lazy download of Jars, as well as programmatic (your code) control of downloads.

Comment: the reason I ask last question is I'm not sure about the 2nd and 3rd question. if lib jars keeping being redownloaded, it might affect the performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating an applet and accessing it from my browser and it seems that all jar files are downloaded immediately and reused as long as the cache is not cleared.

Comment: do you know how to check whether all jars are downloaded on client side when applet starts?

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure all jars are loaded immediately by unjaring them all into one directory, and jar them up into a single jar. Makes also for a shorter archive line.